# Warning thrown by script

Tags: oracle

I have written a script to update a table by passing the parameters to the script. It appears to run just fine but throws the following warnings upon execution :

```
*** Warning:
Problem resolving parameter "ORACLE_CLIENT_VERSION" of "/abinitio/apps30/ste-uat/CitiTech/stdenv/.project.pset":
Parameter:`ORACLE_CLIENT_VERSION' referenced before being defined in pset:`/abinitio/apps30/ste-uat/CitiTech/stdenv/.sandbox.pset'.
```

Can anyone tell me why these warnings are displayed or how to suppress/hide these warnings ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but such a variable ("ORACLE_CLIENT_VERSION") is defined in ruby apps. For example, look [here](https://gitorious.org/opensuse/spacewalk-testsuite-base/source/e68e2508ceb119d04c067b1d9ac6813e97d00da4%3atest/oracle/config.rb) at the config.rb file.

If I were you, I would make just a search in your project for such a config file, and define the ORACLE_CLIENT_VERSION there.